# Корректная сортировка в запросе

Tags: php

Есть таблица с полями, по которым должна быть сортировка. is_vip (0 или 1) и id (primary key).
Как сделать так, чтобы сначала показывались is_vip 1, а затем, ниже, последние добавленные id

Я делаю так

```
$cc->query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE .. ORDER BY is_vip DESC");
```

Для того, чтобы первыми были те, кто имеет is_vip 1. А как ниже в таком же порядке выводить по id ?

Пробовал так

```
$cc->query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE .. ORDER BY is_vip,id DESC");
```

Но это не то..Хотелось бы одним запросом, если такое возможно

Comment: почему вы про второй запрос считаете, что их больше чем один?

Comment: @splash58 Никак не считаю..это моя тщетная попытка. Поэтому прошу помощи )

Comment: `ORDER BY is_vip,id DESC` - выведет сначала isvip=1 , потом 0. если внутри нужен другой порядок id - по возрастанию - `ORDER BY is_vip DESC, id`

Comment: @splash58 понял..спасибо!